# Angular template NOT core

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, azure

I'm looking for an Angular template for Visual Studio 2017 but I do NOT want to use the Core libraries as that requires me to rebuild all my re-usable libraries etc., and I will NEVER host my website on a non Microsoft platform (likely to put it into Azure only).

It would be nice if sign up / sign in is included.

I've tried to "convert" a core project to classic ASP .Net website with a "hack" mentioned on SO but encountered MANY issues

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you find a suitable template in the sidewaffle extension (http://sidewaffle.com/)